# How to write non-ambiguous grammar for LTL formula in bison

Tags: parsing, grammar, bison, context-free-grammar

I am writing a CFG grammar for LTL formula, where atomic proposition are directly expressed by logic formulas. However I am getting amgigouity in my grammar, when I try to implement parenthesis for both - logic and LTL formula (parenthesis for logic formula should have higher priority). Here's my grammar; when I uncomment the parenthesis rule in ltl nonterminal, I got shift/reduce conflict. How to solve it?

```
%left TPLUS TMINUS
%left TMUL TDIV
%left TAND TOR TIMP
%left TRSHIFT TLSHIFT
%left TEQUAL TCNE TCGE TCGT TCLE TCLT
%left TUNTIL TWEAK TFUT TGLOB TREL TNEG

%start ltlformula

%%

ltlformula
  : ltl   {}

formula
  : lexpr  {}
  ;

lterm
  : TLPAREN lexpr TRPAREN         {}
  | arexpr binary_la_oper arexpr  {}
  ;

lnterm
  : lterm      {}
  | TNEG lnterm {}
  ;

lexpr
  : lterm                         {}
  | lexpr binary_ll_oper lnterm    {}
  ;

ltl
  : formula               {}
  | TFUT ltl              {}
  | TGLOB ltl             {}
  | ltl TUNTIL ltl        {}
  | ltl TREL ltl          {}
  | ltl TWEAK ltl         {}
  | TNEG ltl              {}
//  | TLPAREN ltl TRPAREN   { } - here comes the trouble...
  ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem is that an `ltl` can match a parenthesized `lexpr` in two ways:

```
            ltl                          ltl
          /  |  \                         |
   TLPAREN  ltl  TRPAREN               formula
             |                            |
          formula                       lexpr
             |                            |
           lexpr                        lterm
                                      /   |   \
                               TLPAREN  lexpr  TRPAREN
```

If you want to fix this so so that the second parse is not possible, you need to un-factor the grammar so that an `ltl` cannot expand into a `lterm` that expands into a parenthesized expression.  This involves splitting (duplicating) all the rules along that path:

```
ltl: formula_no_paren
   |  ..other ltl rules

formula_no_paren: lexpr_no_paren ;

lexpr_no_paren
    : lterm_no_paren
    |  ... all other lterm rules

lterm_no_paren:  ... all lterm rules that don't start with TLPAREN
```

You can then refactor the other rules to use these no_paren rules to avoid duplicating all the actions:

```
lterm_paren : TLPAREN lexpr TRPAREN ;
lterm : lterm_paren | lterm_no_paren ;

lexpr_paren : lterm_paren ;
lexpr : lexpr_paren | lexpr_no_paren ;
```

You can make this a bit simpler by getting rid of the useless `formula` rule first.

Alternately, you can (ab)use bison's precedence resolution rules by giving the `formula: lexpr` rule an explicit precedence (with `%prec`) that is higher than the precedence of `TRPAREN`.

---

If you want to prefer the second parse, you don't need to do anything, as that is what the default prefer shift over reduce conflict resolution will do.  You can shut up the warning message by giving the `formula: lexpr` rule an explicit precedence that is lower than the precedence of `TPAREN`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see the reason for the ambigouity of the grammar, however I want to avoid "duplication of code". I'm having troubles with the %prec operator of bison - I studied it in the documentation however I don't really understand what it does and how to use. Could you give a small hint?

Answer (score 1):

I have not used Bison, so my answer is predicated on my general knowledge of parsing.

The shift/reduce conflict has to do with that the `ltl` production can match on `TLPAREN` in two possible ways. The first is the rule you're attemping to add. The other is when the parser follows these non-terminals: `formula -> lexpr -> lterm`.

This has to do with the *lookahead* properties of the parser. The link below is to the Bison documentation regarding lookahead and handling shift/reduce conflicts.

http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Lookahead